# tf.print().eval() strange output

Tags: python, tensorflow

Can someone please explain this output to me. I don't understand why tensorflow only evaluates one of these lines:

Input:

```
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np
a=tf.constant([[0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 1, 0],
                  [1, 0, 1],
                  [1, 1, 1],
                  [2, 1, 1]])

b=tf.reshape(tf.range(3),[3,1])
c=tf.matmul(a,b)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.Print(c,[c]).eval()
tf.Print(b,[b]).eval()
```

Output:

```
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]], dtype=int32)
```

Input:

```
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np
a=tf.constant([[0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 1, 0],
                  [1, 0, 1],
                  [1, 1, 1],
                  [2, 1, 1]])

b=tf.reshape(tf.range(3),[3,1])
c=tf.matmul(a,b)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.Print(b,[b]).eval()
tf.Print(c,[c]).eval()
```

Output:

```
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [3]], dtype=int32)
```

So only the last eval() gets called. Why does this happen?

Comment: can you please, remove ".eval()" and use that: tf.Print(b,[b]), than call c.eval() or b.eval()

Comment: Makes no difference Ari.

Comment: Which version? It seems to work for me at HEAD. We just released 0.11, could you try?